# How to aggregate through nested dictionaries, sum its values, and rank them accordingly?

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a MongoDB database containing frequencies of words in the document level as shown below. I have about 175k documents in the same format, totaling about 2.5GB.

```
{
    "_id": xxx,
    "title": "zzz",
    "vectors": {
        "word1": 28,
        "word2": 22,
        "word3": 12,
        "word4": 7,
        "word5": 4
    }
```

Now I want to iterate through all documents, calculate the sum of all frequencies for each word, and get a total ranking of these words I have in the `vectors` field based on the frequencies as such:

```
{
    "vectors": {
        "word1": 223458,
        "word2": 98562,
        "word3": 76433,
        "word4": 4570,
        "word5": 2599
    }
```

`$unwind` does not seem to work here as I have a nested dictionary. I'm relatively new to MongoDB, and I couldn't find answers specific to this. Any ideas?

Comment: you have only 5 words or its dynamic?

Comment: It's dynamic, 500 to 1500 words per document.

Comment: I don't think any better way to do this in mongodb if you have minimum 500 properties, look at the answer by *hhharsha36* but it will not perform well in speed as per your data.

Comment: Indeed it's painfully slow, 5 to 10 mins each query. Would stick with @hhharsha36's answer until I find a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the keys of sub-object to value using `$objectToArray` and then `$unwind` the newly converted array (`$unwind` will work only for array fields, that's why it didn't work for you).

Finally, group by `$vectors.k` where the sub-object key has been converted to value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "vectors": {
        "$objectToArray": "$vectors"
      }
    },
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$vectors"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$vectors.k",
      "count": {
        "$sum": "$vectors.v"
      },
    },
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kr7bLyUdHPw)

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks for your help. + I added ```{'$sort': {'count': -1}}``` to rank it from the most frequent to least, and ```{allowDiskUse: true}``` as the data is relatively large.

Comment: Glad it helped you out ;)  will update the answer and let you know if I find a better solution.